# Intellisense with Ans.MVC5.RazorGen

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using *Ans.MVC5.RazorGen* nuGet package to turn MVC views and controllers into a DLL that can be referenced in multiple projects.  This all works well, other than the intellisense in VS2013 and not being able to right click in the solution explorer and choose add -> view or add -> controller.

Has anyone run into this, and if so do you know of a fix?

Ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it, I've recreated the project that I'm referencing as a MVC project.  Intellisense now all works and I can reference this from my other projects.